# Trying to create an multidimensional array with 100 rows and 3 columns

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

VB beginner here. 
The array i need to create is 3 columns, 100 rows.
The first column will be an integer that increases by two for every row.
The second column will be a date that increases by 15 days.
The third column is similarly like the second column but begins from another day.

I have some codes below I tried but is still lost at what that will do. 
Very grateful if you can help me out on this.

```
Private Sub AutopayPayPeriod()
        Dim row As Int32
        Dim AutopayArray(0 To 10, 0 To 2)
        Dim RCN As Int32 = row
        Dim PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd As Date
        Dim index As Int32
        RCN = 1
        PayPeriodStart = Format(#12/12/2015#, "Short Date")
        PayPeriodEnd = Format(#12/25/2015#, "Short Date")

        For index = 1 To AutopayArray.Length - 1
            AutopayArray(0, 2) = {RCN, PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd}
            PayPeriodStart = PayPeriodStart.AddDays(15)
            PayPeriodEnd = PayPeriodEnd.AddDays(15)
            RCN += 2
            index += 1
            Array.Resize(ByRef AutopayArray, (AutopayArray.Length+=1))

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Honestly, Nico, your solution and Mary are great and I am facing a dilemma to choose the winner. I would say yours would be a problem because if i were to search a particular RCN, I will need to trigger the loop again, instead of saving them into a table. perhaps i was not clear enough i must apologise but if i were to run a report that prints out the list of dates for once, i would surely pick yours. Mary's solution is more user friendly as I think what i needed is a data grid view. Thank you for your contribution though, I will keep that as a learning note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another helpful class in .net is the DataTable. When dealing with rows and columns it may be a good fit.

```
Private Function CreatePayPeriods(RCN As Integer, PayPeriodStart As Date, PayPeriodEnd As Date, NumberOfPeriods As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("RCN", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Pay Period Start Date", GetType(Date))
    dt.Columns.Add("Pay Period End Date", GetType(Date))
    For i = 1 To NumberOfPeriods
        dt.Rows.Add(RCN, PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd)
        PayPeriodStart = PayPeriodStart.AddDays(15)
        PayPeriodEnd = PayPeriodEnd.AddDays(15)
        RCN += 2
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```

To see the results

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = CreatePayPeriods(1, #1/02/2017#, #1/9/2017#, 100)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

A multidimensional array is the wrong data structure for this because you have different data types. Also, having a plain array in your code obscures the intent of the code since nobody can guess what the entries mean without proper documentation.

What you should use is a properly typed `Class` or `Structure`, depending on how you are using it. In the following, I show the variant with a `Class`:

```
Class PeriodInformation
    Public Property RCN As Integer
    Public Property StartDate As Date
    Public Property EndDate As Date
End Class
```

The second thing you might want to change is to use a `List(Of PeriodInformation)` instead of an array because adding and removing items is much simpler. If you stick to the array, resize it once at the beginning instead of every time.

And finally, don't use string representations of dates. Use the actual dates.

The code then look as follows:

```
Private Function AddAutoPayPeriods(firstPayPeriodStart As Date, firstPayPeriodEnd As Date, firstPayPeriodRCN As Integer, numberOfPeriods As Integer) As List(Of PeriodInformation)
    Dim result As New List(Of PeriodInformation)
    For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfPeriods
        result.Add(New PeriodInformation With {.RCN = firstPayPeriodRCN, .StartDate = firstPayPeriodStart, .EndDate = firstPayPeriodEnd})
        firstPayPeriodStart = firstPayPeriodStart.AddDays(15)
        firstPayPeriodEnd = firstPayPeriodEnd.AddDays(15)
        firstPayPeriodRCN += 2
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

We could then call this function like:

```
Dim periods = AddAutoPayPeriods(#12/12/2015#, #12/25/2015#, 1, 10)
```

And finally check what we've got by simply printing all elements:

```
For Each period In periods
    Console.WriteLine($"{period.RCN}: {period.StartDate:d} - {period.EndDate:d}")
Next
```

Which prints

```
1: 12-Dec-15 - 25-Dec-15
3: 27-Dec-15 - 09-Jan-16
5: 11-Jan-16 - 24-Jan-16
7: 26-Jan-16 - 08-Feb-16
9: 10-Feb-16 - 23-Feb-16
11: 25-Feb-16 - 09-Mar-16
13: 11-Mar-16 - 24-Mar-16
15: 26-Mar-16 - 08-Apr-16
17: 10-Apr-16 - 23-Apr-16
19: 25-Apr-16 - 08-May-16
```

Comment: Thanks for tour contribution, it makes alot of sense and i will try that later today

Comment: You could add a constructor to the class that sets the properties. This would make the New code a bit simpler.

Comment: Honestly, Nico, your solution and Mary are great and I am facing a dilemma to choose the winner.

Comment: Just choose whatever you feel more comfortable with. The choice of data structure also depends a lot on the actual use case. So, just pick one - nobody will be mad at you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this method:

```
Private Sub AutopayPayPeriod()
    Dim myArray(2) 'as colomns
    Dim myRows As New ArrayList 'as rows
    Dim PayPeriodStart = Format(#12/12/2015#, "Short Date")
    Dim PayPeriodEnd = Format(#12/25/2015#, "Short Date")

    For myIdx = 1 To 100
        myArray = {(myIdx - 1) * 2 + 1, PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd}
        PayPeriodStart = Format(CDate(PayPeriodStart).AddDays(15), "Short Date")
        PayPeriodEnd = Format(CDate(PayPeriodEnd).AddDays(15), "Short Date")
        myRows.Add(myArray)
    Next
    For myIdx = 1 To 100
        Debug.Print(myRows.Item(myIdx - 1)(0) & ", " & myRows.Item(myIdx - 1)(1) & ", " & myRows.Item(myIdx - 1)(2))
    Next

End Sub
```

The Result are as follows:

```
1, 12/12/2015, 12/25/2015
3, 12/27/2015, 1/9/2016
5, 1/11/2016, 1/24/2016
7, 1/26/2016, 2/8/2016
9, 2/10/2016, 2/23/2016
11, 2/25/2016, 3/9/2016
13, 3/11/2016, 3/24/2016
15, 3/26/2016, 4/8/2016
17, 4/10/2016, 4/23/2016
19, 4/25/2016, 5/8/2016
21, 5/10/2016, 5/23/2016
23, 5/25/2016, 6/7/2016
25, 6/9/2016, 6/22/2016
27, 6/24/2016, 7/7/2016
29, 7/9/2016, 7/22/2016
31, 7/24/2016, 8/6/2016
33, 8/8/2016, 8/21/2016
35, 8/23/2016, 9/5/2016
37, 9/7/2016, 9/20/2016
39, 9/22/2016, 10/5/2016
41, 10/7/2016, 10/20/2016
43, 10/22/2016, 11/4/2016
45, 11/6/2016, 11/19/2016
47, 11/21/2016, 12/4/2016
49, 12/6/2016, 12/19/2016
51, 12/21/2016, 1/3/2017
53, 1/5/2017, 1/18/2017
55, 1/20/2017, 2/2/2017
57, 2/4/2017, 2/17/2017
59, 2/19/2017, 3/4/2017
61, 3/6/2017, 3/19/2017
63, 3/21/2017, 4/3/2017
65, 4/5/2017, 4/18/2017
67, 4/20/2017, 5/3/2017
69, 5/5/2017, 5/18/2017
71, 5/20/2017, 6/2/2017
73, 6/4/2017, 6/17/2017
75, 6/19/2017, 7/2/2017
77, 7/4/2017, 7/17/2017
79, 7/19/2017, 8/1/2017
81, 8/3/2017, 8/16/2017
83, 8/18/2017, 8/31/2017
85, 9/2/2017, 9/15/2017
87, 9/17/2017, 9/30/2017
89, 10/2/2017, 10/15/2017
91, 10/17/2017, 10/30/2017
93, 11/1/2017, 11/14/2017
95, 11/16/2017, 11/29/2017
97, 12/1/2017, 12/14/2017
99, 12/16/2017, 12/29/2017
101, 12/31/2017, 1/13/2018
103, 1/15/2018, 1/28/2018
105, 1/30/2018, 2/12/2018
107, 2/14/2018, 2/27/2018
109, 3/1/2018, 3/14/2018
111, 3/16/2018, 3/29/2018
113, 3/31/2018, 4/13/2018
115, 4/15/2018, 4/28/2018
117, 4/30/2018, 5/13/2018
119, 5/15/2018, 5/28/2018
121, 5/30/2018, 6/12/2018
123, 6/14/2018, 6/27/2018
125, 6/29/2018, 7/12/2018
127, 7/14/2018, 7/27/2018
129, 7/29/2018, 8/11/2018
131, 8/13/2018, 8/26/2018
133, 8/28/2018, 9/10/2018
135, 9/12/2018, 9/25/2018
137, 9/27/2018, 10/10/2018
139, 10/12/2018, 10/25/2018
141, 10/27/2018, 11/9/2018
143, 11/11/2018, 11/24/2018
145, 11/26/2018, 12/9/2018
147, 12/11/2018, 12/24/2018
149, 12/26/2018, 1/8/2019
151, 1/10/2019, 1/23/2019
153, 1/25/2019, 2/7/2019
155, 2/9/2019, 2/22/2019
157, 2/24/2019, 3/9/2019
159, 3/11/2019, 3/24/2019
161, 3/26/2019, 4/8/2019
163, 4/10/2019, 4/23/2019
165, 4/25/2019, 5/8/2019
167, 5/10/2019, 5/23/2019
169, 5/25/2019, 6/7/2019
171, 6/9/2019, 6/22/2019
173, 6/24/2019, 7/7/2019
175, 7/9/2019, 7/22/2019
177, 7/24/2019, 8/6/2019
179, 8/8/2019, 8/21/2019
181, 8/23/2019, 9/5/2019
183, 9/7/2019, 9/20/2019
185, 9/22/2019, 10/5/2019
187, 10/7/2019, 10/20/2019
189, 10/22/2019, 11/4/2019
191, 11/6/2019, 11/19/2019
193, 11/21/2019, 12/4/2019
195, 12/6/2019, 12/19/2019
197, 12/21/2019, 1/3/2020
199, 1/5/2020, 1/18/2020
```

Comment: From the MS Docs "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: Thank you, you have provided me with a lot of ideas how methods can achieve the same result. for now I think I will choose Mary's answer as the choice because it is more user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Another ways are:

```
Private Sub AutopayPayPeriod()
    Dim myArray(2) 'as colomns
    Dim myRows As New Collection'as rows
    Dim PayPeriodStart = Format(#12/12/2015#, "Short Date")
    Dim PayPeriodEnd = Format(#12/25/2015#, "Short Date")

    For myIdx = 1 To 100
        myArray = {(myIdx - 1) * 2 + 1, PayPeriodStart, PayPeriodEnd}
        PayPeriodStart = Format(CDate(PayPeriodStart).AddDays(15), "Short Date")
        PayPeriodEnd = Format(CDate(PayPeriodEnd).AddDays(15), "Short Date")
        myRows.Add(myArray)
    Next
    For myIdx = 1 To 100
        Debug.Print(myRows.Item(myIdx)(0) & ", " & myRows.Item(myIdx)(1) & ", " & myRows.Item(myIdx)(2))
    Next

End Sub
```

But the best way it to use table as Mary said